# Function range with numerical method

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value, maximum

```
In[1]  FunctionRange[{{r^(1/2) Cos[t/2] + r^(1/3) Cos[t/3], 
           r^(1/2) Sin[t/2] + r^(1/3) Sin[t/3]}, 
          0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, {r, t}, {x, y}]
```

Gives

```
Out[1]  0. <= x <= 2. && 0. <= y <= 1.20711
```

with an error message :

[image]

```
FunctionRange: Unable to find the exact range. Returning bounds on the range computed using numeric optimization methods.
```

Loos like mathematica attacked this problem algebraically at first, and failed, and tried numerical method.
My question is : is it possible to attack this problem numerically from the beginning ?

My guess is

```
In[1]  FunctionRange[{{r^(1/2) Cos[t/2] + r^(1/3) Cos[t/3], 
           r^(1/2) Sin[t/2] + r^(1/3) Sin[t/3]}, 
          0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, {r, t}, {x, y}, Method -> blahblah]
```

But I don't know what blahblah is.

Comment: Search shows people have asked pretty much the same question before and nobody seems to ever get an answer from inside Wolfram. If you go to the help page and click on the orange "Details and Options" says nothing about method other than "Automatic" Further down in Examples it has a Method section and that only shows `Method->{"Redued"->True}` From that I tried adding `WorkingPrecision->64" and got no warning message and got the same numeric result that you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

To directly use a numerical approach, specify a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
fr = FunctionRange[{{r^(1/2) Cos[t/2] + r^(1/3) Cos[t/3], 
    r^(1/2) Sin[t/2] + r^(1/3) Sin[t/3]}, 0 <= r <= 1 && 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, {r, 
   t}, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* 0 <= x <= 2.00000000000000 && 0 <= y <= 1.20710678118655 *)

fr /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x]

(* 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[2]) *)
```